# How can i get the JSON format using PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{  
   "apple":[  
      "get",
      "get me an apple"
   ],
   "orange":[  
      "get me one",
      "get some"
   ],
   "banana ":[  
      "cut them all",
      "get them"
   ],

}
```

How can I get the format ? My SQL output when I printed phrases and actions column using print_r($sql); is 
`Array ( [phrases] => get [actions] => apple )
Array ( [phrases] => get me an apple [actions] => apple )
Array ( [phrases] => Get me one [actions] => orange ) 
Array ( [phrases] => Get some [actions] => orange ) 
Array ( [phrases] => cut them all [actions] => Banana ) 
Array ( [phrases] => get them [actions] => Banana )`

Please help.Thanks in advance .....

Comment: Take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.

Answer (score 7):

Try it simple:

```
$tempArray = array();
while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $tempArray[$rec['actions']][] = $rec['phrases'];
}
echo json_encode($tempArray);
```

Comment: @user3445588, this is perfect solution if you get data from mysql object.

Answer (score 0):

The content, which is stored in your `$sql` variable, is of data type `array`. To convert an array into its respective json string representation you need to encode it.

The standard PHP lib provides this functionality through [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

The following snippet should do the job in your example:

```
$tmp = [];
foreach ($sql as $row) {
    $response[$row['actions']][] = $row['phrases'];
}
$json = json_encode($tmp);
```

Comment: likely to not produce OP's desired JSON.